# How to re edit master pages, apply them to all pages, but keep the specific items on each page intact?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I have a master page with a footer and a text box to write specifics on each page.

I needed to re edit the footer and I had already written on the text boxes on each page.

When I re edit the master page some pages do not take the re edit. So I apply the master page to these pages again. But the text box gets reset aswell. How can I avoid that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use one master page as a 'master-master'(A). This is the skeleton page that will only contain f.ex. numbering and title of document. Then add new master (B, C) for f.ex. one section of the document, which perhaps contain content specific to each section. 
When creating master (B, C) select 'Based on master: (A)'. Now define which pages in your document will use master B or C. You won't actually have to use master A. Now when you want to change numbering or title you only change master A. This trickles down to master B and C, and this again trickles down to your actual document pages that are set to using master B and C.